# Linq, how to specify timestamp condition?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `logins` table which records all login and logout activities. I want to look at all login activities of a particular user within 24 hrs. how to do it? something like this:

```
var records = from record in db.Logins
                                where record.Users.UserId == userId
                                    && record.Timestamp <= (DateTime.Now + 24)
                                select record;
```

`record.Timestamp <= (DateTime.Now + 24)` is wrong here. I am using C# 3 + L2E.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently the trouble stems from `DateTime.Now + 24`. This is not possible, because the `DateTime` type does not specify a + operator for `int`.

Did you mean: `DateTime.Now.AddHours(24)`? Or more specifically, `-24` (unless your table contains records that will be added in the future).

```
record.Timestamp >= DateTime.Now.AddHours(-24)
```

To improve performance, you can store the date in a variable.

```
DateTime since = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-24);
var records = from record in db.Logins
    where record.Users.UserId == userId
        && record.Timestamp >= since
    select record;
```

If your timestamp happens to be in ticks, just use `since.Ticks` instead.

Comment: thank you, I think what I want is something like this: (record.Timestamp.AddHours(24)) <= DateTime.Now

Comment: @5YrsLaterDBA: That's probably not a good idea.  For each record you will have to AddHours before comparing it.  With mafutrct's way, you only "add" once and then the rest of the comparisons will be quicker.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to search for all logins between now and 24 hours in the future...

Try:

```
var records = from record in db.Logins 
              where record.Users.UserId == userId 
                    && record.Timestamp >= (DateTime.Now.AddHours(-24)) 
              select record;
```